# For statement ends twice?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
char xxx[100] = {};

cin >> xxx;

for (int i = (sizeof(xxx) / sizeof(*xxx)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    if (xxx[i] != NULL) {

        cout << xxx[i];

    }

}

cout << endl << endl;
main();

return 0;

}
```

The problem is that when I enter "John Smith" into xxx it will output:

```
nhoJ

htimS
```

Why does the "cout << endl << endl" happen in place of space?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour: you must not call `main`.

Comment: Where are you learning this stuff from? Wherever it is, learn it from somewhere else.

Comment: if a `for` statement happens twice does that make it an `eight` statement?

Comment: When you are reading xxx using cin, it reads the string only till first space i.e. xxx will have "John". So, the for loop prints "nhoJ".
Then you call main again. This time cin reads "Smith" and hence, the for loop prints "htimS".
Then main is called again and cin keeps waiting for your input.

Comment: maybe you don't know that `cin >> xxx` reads the first word (not the whole line)

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with cin.getline. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

for (;;) {

    char xxx[100] = {};

    cin.getline(xxx, 100);

    for (int i = (sizeof(xxx) / sizeof(*xxx)) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (xxx[i] != NULL) {

            cout << xxx[i];

        }

    }

    cout << endl << endl;

}

 return 0;

}
```